# Disable possibility to edit sessionstorage variable in console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, session-storage

So, I am creating this website that sets the sessionstorage variable 'logedIn' to true when the user succesfully logs in like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('logedIn', 'true')
```

That variable is used on the other webpages to see if the user is logged in before showing content, so that users who aren't logged in can't have access to the webpage. It works like a charm, but I have noticed, that if I manually type the code in the google chrome console, I can easily change the sessionvariable. This is obviously not wanted.

My question is: how can I resolve this problem?

PS: the reason why I don't use PHP session variables is because the login procedure is done with javascript. When the login button is pressed, ajax sends the given credentials to a php script, which checks the database. If it is successfull, it sends back a code to the ajax complete function, which sets the variable. If you have a better method of doing what I need to do, you are very welcome ;)

Thanks, Zeno

Comment: Do you control the php script that verifies the login? Just set `$_SESSION ['loggedIn'] = 'yup';` in there and check if it is set on each php script. You shouldn't be doing that kind of check in the JS

Comment: Okay, I will do that, thanks for the fast responses!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't and it's not safe. After AJAX result you should set cookies and validate them on every page on the server side.

Comment: So I can't use the php session either?

Comment: You can. Use [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) or your own system based on cookies.

Comment: One more question then, can I set the variable in the php file that checks the database for the given credentials or would that not work/not be safe?

Comment: For example: you have database with columns id, username, password, session, every time user login you are changing session's and [cookie's](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) value to random string. When someone loads page you are doing simple query to select row with stored string.

Comment: If you use cookies, remeber that the user can change them to whatever they want so do not rely on them for anything security-related

Comment: @zenodhaene it's safe, but remember to filter data, so you'll be sure there isn't way to do sql injection.